# Sorting a textfile that contains player name and score in descending order

Tags: c++, sorting, text-files

I am trying to open a text file and then rearrange it in descending order, to show who has the highest score. In the text file there's the player name and their score.

I've managed to print out the textfile in c++, but I cannot find a way to sort it since the variables are in the text file.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct player {
    string name;
    int score;
    int position;
};

int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("C:/Users/kkpet/Desktop/highscore.txt");
    if (inFile.is_open()) {
        while (getline(inFile, line)) {
            player x;
            ifstream inFile;
            inFile.open("C:/Users/kkpet/Desktop/highscore.txt");
            cout << line << '\n';
        }
        inFile.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to open text";
}
```

Comment: split task into smaller steps (functions): 1. Read all players  form stream (use `std::vector`)2. open file 3. printing result to stream 4. sorting 5. main. It will be easier for you to complete each task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your text file looks like this:

```
Name1 1
Name2 1
Name4 5
Name3 6
```

you could do something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("/C:/Users/kkpet/Desktop/highscore.txt");
    if (inFile.is_open()) {
        std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string> > score_vector;
        std::string name;
        int score;
        while (inFile >> name >> score) {
            score_vector.push_back(std::make_pair(score, name));
            std::cout << line << '\n';
        }
        inFile.close();
        std::sort(score_vector.begin(), score_vector.end());
        std::reverse(score_vector.begin(), score_vector.end());
        for(auto it = score_vector.begin(); it != score_vector.end(); ++it){
            std::cout << "Name: " << it->second << " Score: " << it->first << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Unable to open text";
}
```

You first read the file line by line using `inFile << name << score` directly gives you the name and score of the player. You then create a pair out of them with score as first, which just makes it easier to sort, you could also sort by the second element of a pair using your own compare function, but for simplicity I put it this way around. Then you can easily sort the vector with the `std::sort` method. Afterwards it needs to be reverted.

Full code with custom compare function:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

// This is a compare funciton for the sort algorithm of std::sort. See [1]
bool compareScorePair(std::pair<std::string, int>&a, std::pair<std::string, int>&b){
    if(a.second > b.second){return true;}
    if(a.second == b.second){return a.first.compare(b.first) > 0;}
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("C:/Users/kkpet/Desktop/highscore.txt");
    if (inFile.is_open()) {
        std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int> > score_vector;
        std::string name;
        int score;
        while (inFile >> name >> score) { // Can be used to directly assign istream data to variables. See [2]
            score_vector.push_back(std::make_pair(name, score)); // Storing data as pair, to keep relationships between score and name.
        }
        inFile.close();
        std::sort(score_vector.begin(), score_vector.end(), compareScorePair); // Sort the vector with the custom compare function, See top of code.
        int place = 1;
        //auto is used purely for convenience. auto represents std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int> >::iterator here.
        for(auto it = score_vector.begin(); it != score_vector.end(); ++it){ 
            std::cout << "Place: " << place << " Name: " << it->first << " Score: " << it->second << std::endl;
            ++place;
        }
        // The whole for loop could look like this:
        /*
        for(uint i = 0; i < score_vector.size(); ++i){
            std::string name_out = score_vector[i].first;
            int score_out = score_vector[i].second;
            std::cout << "Place: " << i << " Name: " << name_out << " Score: " << score_out << std::endl;
        }
        */
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Unable to open text";
}
```

Output:

```
Place: 1 Name: Name3 Score: 6
Place: 2 Name: Name4 Score: 5
Place: 3 Name: Name2 Score: 1
Place: 4 Name: Name1 Score: 1
```

Links:
[1]: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare
[2]: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/
Information on pair:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair
Information on iterators (see auto keyword):
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterators-c-stl/

Comment: You could also iterate through the sorted vector using reverse iterators.

Comment: Thankyou verymuch, im trying to understand the code, and is there any other ways to do this? ive never used auto before so im taking my time reading each line one by one

Comment: Please see edit for further information. And please accept answer, if it solves your problem, many first timers here on SO forget about it ;)

Comment: Thankyou very much, will do slowly understanding and why arent we using simple bubble sort?

Comment: https://github.com/flufyD/highscore/blob/master/highscore.txt                                        This is the text file im trying to sort

Answer (score 0):

No need to use C++ for this problem! Just enter this in the shell prompt.

```
sort -rk 2 highscore.txt > sorted_scores.txt
```

Explanation:
'sort' sorts a file, typically by the first letter.
The -k 2 option means to sort by the second column.
The -r option means to reverse (so highest score is on top).